# Javascript array has data but length is zero

Tags: javascript, arrays

**EDIT: this appears to be a sync issue due to me not understanding promises correctly. I assumed that the ".then" waited for the promise to resolve. This is apparently not the case.**

I am encountering a strange error that I've never seen before.

I have this code which produces the following output in the Chrome console.

Clearly it is an array and it has data and a length, but when I print the length property it is zero. (I also can't iterate over it with map)

I'm really confused, any help would be much appreciated.

```
const readFile = (file) => (
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = () => {
      resolve(fr.result);
    };
    fr.readAsText(file);
  })
);

const readFiles = (files) => {
  const readFiles = [];
  files.forEach((file) => (readFile(file)).then((data) => readFiles.push({name: file.name, data })));
  return readFiles;
};

const scenes = readFiles(...grabbed from file picker dialog...)
console.log('scenes: ', ui.value.scenes);
console.log('length: ', ui.value.scenes.length);
```

[image: console]

Comment: it may be that ui.value.scenes is getting updated after the log statements

Comment: By any chance is `scenes` being populated *asynchronously*?

Comment: This is not enough to identify the problem. Please [edit] the question and include a [mcve].

Comment: No, it is being populated synchronously. I can print it multiple times with the result being correct in the console, but length is always zero when I print it.

Comment: Give us some more code plz

Comment: Try opening the console **before** running the code to avoid console-related sync problems.

Comment: Have you read the little `i` icon next to `[]`?

Comment: @Xufox it says "value was evaluated just now" which leads me to believe this is a sync issue and the value is being updated asynchronously. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Dear users answering this question: when a question has been clearly asked/answered 1e6 times, don't answer it again: just mark it as a duplicate, as @Xufox did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you return from read file is a promise so you should read the resolved value inside `then` method like this

```
 readFile().then( (scenes) => {
     console.table(scenes)
 }
```

The reason you could see values in console is because when using `console.log` in Chrome and Firefox it is a **live version** of the object that might be changed from later code (from promise resolve).
 If you want to print **state of object in time** you can run `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`
Here is a snippet from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

> Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of
>   Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference
>   to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at
>   the moment in time you call console.log(), but it is the value of the
>   object at the moment you click it open.